# TBXML issue with autorelease on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, autorelease, ios5

i have try TBXML in iOS 5..

but as you know, autorelease is not use again in iOS 5..
so it's give me error when i start to run the apps..

is anybody get solve this problem??

or anyone can tell me another light xml parser??

Comment: You're better off asking about this in the Apple Developer Forums where they are more likely to tell you how to deal with this.

Comment: yes i know it still NDA.. i just want to try iOS 5.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS5 is still under NDA.

But per the LLVM project docs, you can see that you can turn off ARC for specific files in your project with -fno-objc-arc

See [LLVM docs on ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

But, as @Abizern suggests, you should ask this on Apple's Developer forums instead.